# how can i crunch numbers in a non-blocking way?

Tags: javascript, performance, backbone.js

I have a lineCollection of models that represent lines of a graph. Each line crunches through a dataCollection and generates averages once. For one line, its very snappy.

After the dataCollection is fetched, I have a listener to crunch the data for each line.

```
lineCollection.invoke('setData')
```

However, this kind of freezes the browser. My next approach was to try to set a timeout to hopefully stop blocking the ui:

```
lineCollection.each(function(model) {
  setTimeout(model.setData, Math.round(Math.random() * 20));
});
```

This still sorta freezes the whole process. How can I tell the browser to crunch the data in the background?

---

*Edit*

"crunch the data" in my case is to zip variable sets of ~3600 length arrays, average each slice, and format ~3600 date objects.

```
// x axis
var xs = _.map(times, this.formatTime);

// y axis
var values = _.map(allSamples, function(samples) {
  return _.pluck(samples, 'value');
});
var avgs = _.map(_.zip.apply(_, values), _.avg);
var ys = _.compact(avgs);

// graph data
var data = { x: xs.slice(xs.length - ys.length), y: ys };
```

Comment: How many items are in the collection? You may want to batch them into fewer `setTimeout` calls.

Comment: And what do you mean by "crunch the data"? What exactly is happening? Are you updating the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely look into [worker threads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

Comment: true, yeah really didn't want to decouple the logic into different scripts, ugh